# How do I get my GPG fingerprint in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, gnupg

I wish to get some help on how I can get my GPG fingerprint on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The few guides I have seen online have not been so clear to me.

Thanks.

Comment: The command `gpg2 --fingerprint` will list all fingerprints for keys installed in in `~/.gnupg` folder of the current user.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli In my case, it doesn't.